# Germany Employment Visa - "Have you lived in Germany before?" What is considered as living?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I'm applying for a German national visa (employment) from India. Annexure for employment visa has a question: "Have you **lived** in Germany before?".
I've earlier stayed in Germany for 20 days on a business Visa, but never had a Residence permit there. How to answer this?
There is a question in the Visa application itself - "Have you ever *been* to Germany before?", and I have answered 'Yes'.

Comment: They are asking if you have ever been on a settlement track, so you would answer 'no' and for the 'have you ever been' your answer would be 'yes'.

Comment: @JoErNanO link for your answer please

Comment: Your request for sources will be much more effective if you post it as a comment on *the answer for which you are seeking clarification* rather than on your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The form is asking if you have ever been in Germany on a settlement track.  This would include spouse visas, family permits, work permits, asylum claims, study visas, and the like.

Therefore, in your application you should answer:

- Q: "Have you lived in Germany before?" - **A: No**
- Q: "Have you ever been to Germany before?" - **A: Yes**

Comment: This is correct as my Visa application was accepted. Thanks.